# Click on a button in Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use Excel VBA to navigate to a webpage, fill in a form, and click a button. Right now the code I'm using loads the webpage and fills in the webpage form fine. But the code I'm using to try and click the ("Lookup") button gives me a Run-time error '424': Object Required.

Any help would be so appreciated.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Sub WebForm()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "https://lambda.byu.edu/ae/prod/person/cgi/personLookup.cgi"
IE.Visible = True
While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

IE.document.all("inpSearchPattern").Value = "Some Last Name"
IE.document.all("doNewLookup(document.personxref)").Click

End Sub
```

Comment: `"doNewLookup(document.personref)"` is a Javascript function call, not a button. Javascript function calls are not objects, and they don't have a `Click` method.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Very helpful. Wasn't going to figure that out on my own. That said, is there a way to use VBA to click the "Lookup" button?

Comment: Without being able to see the source code of that page, that can't be answered. I'd suspect they may have designed it to prevent exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this one**, it worked for me.

```
Sub WebForm()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "https://lambda.byu.edu/ae/prod/person/cgi/personLookup.cgi"
IE.Visible = True
While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

IE.Document.all("inpSearchPattern").Value = "J*n"

Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

i = 0
    While i < objCollection.Length
       'MsgBox "i= " & i & " Name " & objCollection(I).Name & _
        " Value " & objCollection(I).Value & _
        " Type " & objCollection(I).Type
       If (objCollection(i).Value = "Lookup" And objCollection(i).Type = "button") Then
           Set objElement = objCollection(i)
       End If
        i = i + 1
    Wend

    objElement.Click    ' click button to load the form

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked for me too! Can't thank you enough. Again, I wasn't gonna figure this one out on my own.